# JS Getting a new array with just the elements that contain certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this array

```
"myArray": [
 {
     'specialValue' : 111,
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
 },
{
     'specialValue' : 555,
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
 },
 {
     'specialValue' : 111,
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
 },
 {
     'specialValue' : 555,
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
 },
]
```

I want to make a new array that contains only those objects (with all their properties) that have same `specialValue`
Please help me to do it with js

EDIT: The specialValue is not know beforehand. I just give this array as a structure example.

Comment: What do you mean by "same"? Do you mean unique values? Do you mean some specified value? How to you want to handle the "other values, arrays, objects and so on" in the entries with the same `specialValue`?

Comment: I want objects that have specialValue = 111 to go into a separate array, the ones with specialValue = 555 to go into a separate array and so on. And I do not know the specialValue beforehand. I get a JSON response. And that's only where I have the specialValues

Comment: This is the problem called "grouping", often implemented in a function called "groupBy". Please search for that.

Comment: Instead of clarifying your question in comments, please edit the question to make it clearer. Perhaps you want to say *I wanted to make new array**s** each containing only those objects (with all their properties) that have the same `specialValue`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group it with a hash table.

```js
var object = { "myArray": [{ 'specialValue': 111, propA: true }, { 'specialValue': 555, propC: true }, { 'specialValue': 111, propB: true }, { 'specialValue': 555, propD: true }, ] },
    grouped = object.myArray.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.specialValue]) {
                hash[a.specialValue] = [];
                r.push(hash[a.specialValue]);
            }
            hash[a.specialValue].push(a);
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var object = { "myArray": [{ 'specialValue': 111, propA: true }, { 'specialValue': 555, propC: true }, { 'specialValue': 111, propB: true }, { 'specialValue': 555, propD: true }, ] },
    grouped = object.myArray.reduce((map =>
        (r, a) =>
           (!map.has(a.specialValue) && map.set(a.specialValue, r[r.push([]) - 1]), map.get(a.specialValue).push(a), r))(new Map), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
  var myArray = [{
    'specialValue': 111,
    'other values': ["arrays"]
  }, {
    'specialValue': 555,
    'other values': {}
  }, {
    'specialValue': 111,
    'other values': "abc"
  }, {
    'specialValue': 555,
    'other values': 123
  }];

var res = myArray.reduce((obj, prop) => ({specialValue:key} = prop
          , obj[key] = obj[key] ? [...obj[key], prop] : [prop], obj), {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @HaykSafaryan plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ufxumSesEbgRtYcmGzKf?p=preview

Comment: You're essentially plucking out `specialValue`, but this does not satisfy the OP's requirement to *contains only those objects that have same specialValue*j, and it throws away the other information in each element.

Comment: @torazaburo That is how interpreted Question. Current requirement is not clear. There is no special value other than the name of the property.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over all elements and check the special value like this:

```js
var myArray = [
 {
     'specialValue' : 111,
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
 },
{
     'specialValue' : 555,
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
 },
 {
     'specialValue' : 111,
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
 },
 {
     'specialValue' : 555,
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
 },
];
  
var result = pickBySpecialValue(myArray, 111);
console.log(result);

function pickBySpecialValue(array, specialValue){
  var matchingItems = [];
  for(var i=0;i < array.length;i++){
    if(array[i].specialValue === specialValue){
      matchingItems.push(array[i]);
    }                               
  }
  return matchingItems;
}
```

Comment: This is just an awkward way to write what `filter` could do.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var myArray = [
    {
     'specialValue' : 111,
    'name' : 'test1'
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
    },
    {
     'specialValue' : 555,
    'name' : 'test2'
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
    },
    {
     'specialValue' : 111,
    'name' : 'test3'
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
    },
    {
     'specialValue' : 555,
    'name' : 'test4'
     // other values,arrays,objects and so on
    },
    ];
    var customArray = [];
    myArray.forEach(function(element){
    if(element.specialValue === 111) {
       customArray.push(element);
    }
    });
    console.log(customArray); // customArray contains the required value
```

Comment: This is an OK solution **if** the problem is to find elements with some pre-specified `specialValue`, but what you have written is just an awkward form of `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

We'll first group the elements by their special value:

```
grouped = groupBy(arr, e => e.specialValue);
```

That will return something of the form

```
{
   111: [{specialValue: 111, other stuff}, {specialValue: 111, other stuff}],
   555: [{specialValue: 555, other stuff}, {specialValue: 555, other stuff}]
}
```

Next, we'll combine all those objects for each special value into one, assuming that's what you want to do:

```
for (value in grouped) {
  grouped[value] = Object.assign({}, ...grouped[value]);
}
```

That will give you something like

```
{
   111: {specialValue: 111, combined other stuff},
   555: {specialValue: 555, combined other stuff}
}
```

If you want just the values from the above, then grab them:

```
Object.keys(result).map(key => result[key])
```

That will give you

```
[
   {specialValue: 111, combined other stuff},
   {specialValue: 555, combined other stuff}
]
```

Writing `groupBy` is left as an exercise. There are plenty of examples around SO, or you could use underscore's `_.groupBy`. If you want a real simple one, it would just be

```
function groupBy(arr, keyFunc) {
  const result = {};

  for (elt of arr) {
    const key = keyFunc(elt);
    if (!(key in result)) result[key] = [];
    result[key].push(elt);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a hashmap of specialValues as keys and an array of their matching entries as values

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    'specialValue' : 111,
    // other values,arrays,objects and so on
  },
  {
    'specialValue' : 555,
    // other values,arrays,objects and so on
  },
  {
    'specialValue' : 111,
    // other values,arrays,objects and so on
  },
  {
    'specialValue' : 555,
    // other values,arrays,objects and so on
  },
];
specialArrays = {};
for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (!Array.isArray(specialArrays[myArray[i].specialValue])) {
    specialArrays[myArray[i].specialValue] = [];
  }
  specialArrays[myArray[i].specialValue].push(myArray[i]);
}
console.log(specialArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value you can use JavaScript's 'filter' function.

```
var specificVal = 555;
var newArray = myArray.filter(function(val) {
    return val.specialValue === specificVal;
});
```